# How do I get the height of an image or GridLayout after it displays

Tags: nativescript

I'm using angular. I have an image carousel. I have two gridlayouts, one on top of the other. The top grid has the naviagation buttons. I want them to be positioned in the center of the image top to bottom. I'm trying to do that based on the image height, as it will differ depending on the device size. How do I get either the view image height or the containing grid height?

```
<GridLayout class="template_body" rows="auto,50*,auto" columns="*" #sv>
    <GridLayout row="0" #wviWrapper>
            <!-- <web-view id="wvi" #wvi></web-view> -->
            <template-text *ngIf="lessonDetail.instruction" [data]="lessonDetail.instruction" [version]="version" [screenwidth]="screenWidth"></template-text>
    </GridLayout>
    <GridLayout row="1">
        <player-carousel [data]='lessondata' [itemindex]="lessonindex" (loaded)="onCarouselLoaded($event)" [clength]="carouselLength"></player-carousel>
    </GridLayout>
    <GridLayout row="1">
        <FlexboxLayout backgroundColor="#3c495e" alignItems="center" justifyContent="space-between" verticalAlignment="top" orientation="horizontal" class="button-group" #bg>
            <Button text="&#xf104;" appDebounceTap (debounceClick)="getItem(-1)" [debounceTime]="1000" id="backbtn" col="0" alignSelf="flex-end" class="back-btn fas" horizontalAlignment="left"></Button>
            <Button text="&#xf105;" appDebounceTap (debounceClick)="getItem(1)" [debounceTime]="1000" id="nextbtn" col="1" alignSelf="flex-end" class="next-btn fas" horizontalAlignment="right"></Button>
        </FlexboxLayout>
    </GridLayout>
</GridLayout>
```

I'm using angular:

Comment: Listen to [layoutChanged](https://docs.nativescript.org/api-reference/classes/_ui_core_view_.view#layoutchangedevent) event and then use [getMeasuredHeight()](https://docs.nativescript.org/api-reference/classes/_ui_core_view_.view#getmeasuredheight) method on the view instance. You may also get the height of image form [ImageSource](https://docs.nativescript.org/api-reference/classes/_image_source_.imagesource#height)

Comment: Could you tell me how to do this? <StackLayout row="0" #imageRow class="imgRow" (layoutChanged)="componentLoaded(imageRow)">
        <Image #cImage></Image>
    </StackLayout>